# Arbitrary specific integer c program

Tags: c, string, calculator, unsigned-integer

So, recently I've asked question about arbitrary specific integer calculator program. It scans two string and is supposed to calculate it's sum and difference, multiplication, division and modulus. So far I think I'm really close to finishing the sum difference and multiplication functions. Here is how my code look like for addition function:

```
void sum(char* a, char* b)
{
    //initializing values
    int len1,len2,i;
    int carry=0;
    char *r;
    // counting the digits
    len1=strlen(a);
    len2=strlen(b);
    // checking which array is longer
    if (len1>=len2)
    {
        // if first array is longer we allocate enough memory for the result
        r=(char*)malloc((len1+1)*sizeof(char));
        // starting from the LSB
        for (i=0; i<=len2; ++i)
            {   // mod 10 to extract only the last digit of the sum
                // that becomes our new digit
            *(r+len1-i)=(*(a+len1-i) + *(b+len2-i) + carry)%10;
            carry=(*(a+len1-i)+*(b+len2-i))/10;
            }
            // copying the rest of the digits
        for (i=len2+1; i<=len1; ++i)
            *(r+len1-i)=*(a+len1-i);

    }
    //case when the other number has more digits
    else
    {
         r=(char*)malloc((len2+1)*sizeof(char));
        for (i=0; i<=len1; ++i)
            {
            *(r+len2-i)=(*(a+len1-i)+*(b+len2-i)+carry)%10;
            carry=(*(a+len1-i)+*(b+len2-i))/10;
            }
        for (i=len1+1; i<=len2; ++i)
            *(r+len2-i)=*(b+len2-i);
    }
    // printing the result
    printf("The result is: \n %s \n", r);
}
```

The problem is when I try to call for the function in main the end result just gives errors, even though there are not any errors while compiling the code. It might be a problem in main so here is how my main looks like.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *fi=NULL, *se=NULL;
    char o;
    int i=0;
    fp= fopen("/CalculatorHistory.txt", "r+");
    opening();
    fi=(char*)malloc(60*sizeof(char));
    se=(char*)malloc(60*sizeof(char));
    while(i<2)
    {
        first();
        scanf("%s", fi);
        // I am not sure when im saving pointer arrays, if it works like this
        // or i should save it in a for loop
        fprintf(fp, fi);
        oper();
        scanf(" %c", &o);
        fprintf(fp, o);
        second();
        scanf("%s", se);
        fprintf(fp, se);
        switch (o)
        {
        case '+':
            sum(fi, se);
        case  '-':
            sub(fi, se);
        case '*':
            mul(fi, se);
        case '/':
            div(fi, se);
        case '%':
            mod(fi, se);

         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I hope that somebody can help me. I'm pretty lost and still really new to c programming.

Comment: Not related, but I am pretty convinced that array indexing notation is both cleaner and more readable than pointer arithmetic/dereferencing.

Comment: Writing the body of the addition code out twice is not a good idea.  You could determine the longer and shorter strings and set up pointers to suit a single loop that scans over the information.  You could use `char *lhs, *rhs` and set `lhs` to point to the longer string and `rhs` to point to the shorter (or vice versa), and then do the computation in terms of those variables.  It's not clear that you're null terminating your result string.

Comment: You might be interested in other ways of solving your problem, like https://www.nongnu.org/bnf/

Comment: or slightly more complex use flex+bison: https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/flex-bison/9780596805418/ch01.html... it's telling that both of these use a desktop calculator as their 'hello world' examples.